# Change grub options on Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, grub2

I'm trying to modify GRUB such that it only shows

```
Fedora 36
Windows 11
```

with Fedora being the default after a 10-second timeout that is shown.

I have removed the only other Fedora kernel, but I still see something like

```
Fedora 36 5.18.x
Fedora 36 (0xxx)
Windows Boot Manager on xxx
UEFI settings
```

I used PopOS before which allowed me to change this via grub-customiser, but that doesn't seem possible here given BLSCFG.

Additionally, the resolution is 1920x1200. I couldn't get `vbeinfo` or `videoinfo` to work, even inside grub console. However, `xrandr` shows 1280x800 as an option.

I have tried setting `/etc/default/grub` to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="true"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG="true"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1280x800"
```

However, running `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` gives

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ... 
error: ../grub-core/script/lexer.c:352:syntax error. 
error: ../grub-core/script/lexer.c:352:Incorrect command. 
error: ../grub-core/script/lexer.c:352:syntax error. 
Syntax error at line 217 
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file. 
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub 
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with 
/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

And upon restarting, the changes have not been put into effect.

**EDIT:** I think the errors may be caused by whatever grub-customiser tried to do. How can I just reset everything and start again?

**EDIT2:** I re-installed GRUB as mentioned [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Instructions_for_UEFI-based_systems), but I still get exactly the same error.

**EDIT3:** The relevant line (217) is

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_uefi-firmware_proxy ###

if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then

fi # <- 217
### END /etc/grub.d/33_uefi-firmware_proxy ###
```

**EDIT4:**
`/etc/grub.d/33_uefi-firmware_proxy` links to `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/uefi-firmware` which contains the seemingly relevant:

```
if [ "\$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    menuentry '$LABEL' \$menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
    }
fi
```

Note my computer does support efi (`/sys/firmware/efi` exists).

Comment: Do you have a backup of your `/etc/default/grub` file?  You could have had what you want by setting GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU to false, but now you’ve lost a bunch of necessary information in your grub file.

Comment: @jsbillings "had what you want" in what sense? I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"`, added `GRUB_GFX_MODE="1280x800"`, added `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"` and removed `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"`.

Comment: You only wanted one line for Fedora.

Comment: @jsbillings How do I achieve that now?

Comment: Restore the original contents of the file, and set `GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=“false”`

Comment: @jsbillings Same error

Comment: And you’ve restored all the files to the original before you started editing things?

Comment: @jsbillings Yes I undid the changes mentioned. I've added some edits with the files seemingly causing the issues.

Comment: All the proxy files are from grub-customizer. A thought a full reinstall of grub housecleaned /etc/grub.d so all proxy files removed. If you still have proxy files change executable bit on proxy file  `sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/XXXX.sh`, so not run as part of update. From a grub command line to see available settings pressing <c> & escape to get back to menu:
`vbeinfo` You do not need all the scripts, so you can turn off execute bit on others also.

Comment: @oldfred I tried removing everything inside `grub.d` and doing `dnf reinstall grub2-efi shim`. I get ```Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.new file attached.``` when running `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Is error still from proxy file(s)? And then are you housecleaning an old install's grub files, so new install still has them? New install of grub should only have working grub files. Do you have an old copy of /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg? And you manually can copy that back  or manually create a simple version, just so you can boot once & then update.

Comment: Perhaps you need to purge grub-customizer. Is it still installed & then updating system? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168054/how-to-fix-kernel-issue-after-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04 `sudo apt-get purge grub-customizer`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the old boot option, go to the (/boot/loader/entries) directory with the root user and then delete the file that is related to the old system kernel and has the .conf extension, and then reboot the system.
You can see that the old boot option has been removed from the menu.

For example, this is a picture of the boot menu of my system and I want to remove the boot option (ef8547eded9a4dc090162681ff9bbb34-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64)

Look at the image below:
[image]

now i run this commands:
[image]

and after reboot my system you show:
[image]